# SQL invalid column name Site.LocationLat,

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE #Data(
    [LocationLat] float NULL, 
    [LocationLong] float NULL, 
    [LocationHeight] float NULL,
```

When I am creating table and insert data that time error occurs.
Invalid Column name.

```
INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT  @ServerName,
        Site.LocationLat, /*Error occur invalid column name */
        Site.LocationLong, /*Error occur invalid column name */
        Site.LocationHeight,  /*Error occur invalid column name */
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Post your DDL of the Site table so others can easily guide you with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server try to wrap your column names with [].

```
INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT @ServerName, [Site.LocationLat], [Site.LocationLong], [Site.LocationHeight]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Site` doesn't mean anything without a `FROM` clause.  Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    SiteName varchar(255),
    [LocationLat] float NULL, 
    [LocationLong] float NULL, 
    [LocationHeight] float NULL
); 


INSERT INTO #Data (SiteName, LocationLat, LocationLong, LocationLong)
    SELECT @ServerName, s.LocationLat, s.LocationLong, s.LocationHeight, 
    FROM Site s;
```

This assumes you have a table called `Site` with the appropriate columns.

Comment: @ParthShah - "not working" isn't helpful feedback. At the least, the error message *should* have changed. Rather than just saying "not working", tell us *what the error message has changed to*.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following code

> CREATE TABLE #Data (
>       SiteName varchar(255),
>       [LocationLat] float NULL, 
>       [LocationLong] float NULL, 
>       [LocationHeight] float NULL );

**

> INSERT INTO #Data (SiteName, LocationLat, LocationLong,
>   LocationHeight)
>       SELECT @@ServerName, s.LocationLat, s.LocationLong, s.LocationHeight, 
>       FROM Site s;

**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your #Data table it's your Site table.  So we really need to see the definition for that.  I suspect it doesn't have a LocationLat column.